# Pandas - Using QCut Rankings From One Dataframe to Categorize a Second Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, qcut

I am looking to get quartiles from one dataframe (grouped by PriceDate) and then use the ranges to categorize the values in a second data frame with the same dates.

So in the data set below

For 10-1, we have the following bins   (-0.001, 3.2] and  (3.2, 9.3]
For 10-2, we have the following bins    (0.699, 6.5] and (6.5, 10.0]

What I am looking to do us to have the rank column of the df1 be :

**0** if the date in the second column is 10-1 and the price between -0.001 and 3.2

**1** if the date in the second column is 10-1 and the price between 3.2 and 9.3

etc..

But I can't figure out the logic to make this work

Would somebody please set me on the right path?

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Price':[4.4, 3.6, 9.2, 3.4], 'PriceDate':['2023-10-01', '2023-10-01','2023-10-01', '2023-10-02']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Price':[0.0, 3.6, 9.3, 4.5, 2.9, 3.2, 1.0, 6.7, 8.7, 9.8, 3.4, .7, 2.2, 6.5, 3.4, 1.7, 9.4, 10.0], 'PriceDate':['2023-10-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02']})

df2['Rank'] = df2.groupby(['PriceDate'])['Price'].transform(
                   lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 2,labels=False,duplicates="drop"))
df2['labels'] = df2.groupby(['PriceDate'])['Price'].transform(
                   lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 2,duplicates="drop"))
```

Sample data can be found https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/txqtq4ezsjdn0g9hcrcg2/subsetfills.csv?rlkey=ndtt9xskrien8a4r9p4pr87od&dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/fwpgnwp2wh3e83ohyxkdb/allfills.csv?rlkey=n9kmx0bge4x5ayw12g4g2qfll&dl=0

Sample code for this data that doesn't work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df1=pd.read_csv("c:/temp/subsetfills.csv",index_col=False)
df2=pd.read_csv("c:/temp/allfills.csv",index_col=False)


ref = df2.groupby('Trade_Date')['ExecPrice'].apply(lambda g: pd.qcut(g, q=2, retbins=True)[1])
ref = pd.DataFrame(ref).reset_index().rename(columns={'ExecPrice': 'Bins'})
ref

df3 = pd.merge(df1, ref, on='Trade_Date', how='left')
df3



def bin_price(g):
    # Get the bins range
    bins = g['Bins'].iloc[0]

    # In some case the value Price in df1 might outside the bin range
    # You can modify here:
    bins = [-np.inf] + bins[1:-1].tolist() + [np.inf]
    
    
    bin_value = pd.cut(g['Price'], bins, labels=False)

    return bin_value


df3['GroupPrice'] = df3.groupby('ExecPrice', group_keys=False).apply(bin_price)
df3
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand fully... do you want to compute the bins?

Comment: I'm computing the bins based on the values in df2 and want to put the price values into those bins.  Think of df2 as all of prices for a day and df1 as the prices I paid for the day.  I want to know what "rank" my prices were based on the ranks of all the prices in df1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question:  I make change 1st value in `df1` to `-4.4` so it will account for all the possible scenarios.

**Data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Price':[-4.4, 3.6, 9.2, 3.4], 'PriceDate':['2023-10-01', '2023-10-01','2023-10-01', '2023-10-02']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Price':[0.0, 3.6, 9.3, 4.5, 2.9, 3.2, 1.0, 6.7, 8.7, 9.8, 3.4, .7, 2.2, 6.5, 3.4, 1.7, 9.4, 10.0], 'PriceDate':['2023-10-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-01', '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02',  '2023-10-02']})
```

**Step 01:** Create bins range with `groupby`:

```
ref = df2.groupby('PriceDate')['Price'].apply(lambda g: pd.qcut(g, q=2, retbins=True)[1])
ref = pd.DataFrame(ref).reset_index().rename(columns={'Price': 'Bins'})
ref
```

The `ref` looks like this:

```
    PriceDate              Bins
0  2023-10-01   [0.0, 3.2, 9.3]
1  2023-10-02  [0.7, 6.5, 10.0]
```

**Step 02:** Merge `ref` to `df`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, ref, on='PriceDate', how='left')
df

   Price   PriceDate              Bins
0   -4.4  2023-10-01   [0.0, 3.2, 9.3]
1    3.6  2023-10-01   [0.0, 3.2, 9.3]
2    9.2  2023-10-01   [0.0, 3.2, 9.3]
3    3.4  2023-10-02  [0.7, 6.5, 10.0]
```

**Step 03:** Create a define function:

```
def bin_price(g):
    # Get the bins range
    bins = g['Bins'].iloc[0]

    # In some case the value Price in df1 might outside the bin range
    # You can modify here:
    bins = [-np.inf] + bins[1:-1].tolist() + [np.inf]
    
    
    bin_value = pd.cut(g['Price'], bins, labels=False)

    return bin_value
```

This line `bins = [-np.inf] + bins[1:-1].tolist() + [np.inf]` is very important. Since value in df1 might be out of range bins. Adding +/- inf allow you to capture all possible scenarios.

**Step 04:** Using `groupby` then `apply`:

```
df['GroupPrice'] = df.groupby('PriceDate', group_keys=False).apply(bin_price)
df

   Price   PriceDate              Bins  GroupPrice
0   -4.4  2023-10-01   [0.0, 3.2, 9.3]           0
1    3.6  2023-10-01   [0.0, 3.2, 9.3]           1
2    9.2  2023-10-01   [0.0, 3.2, 9.3]           1
3    3.4  2023-10-02  [0.7, 6.5, 10.0]           0
```

Comment: I almost got this to work, but got "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" when I tried to do the apply with my actual data set.. Any ideas what might be causing that?  Thanks

Comment: I need more details. Otherwise, there is no way I can figure out what is wrong. At least, edit your post, show a picture of where it goes wrong

Comment: More details will be coming - fixed one problem, have another strange one.  Thank you

Comment: @StumblingThroughDataScience: the error happens because (1) When import, you should use `parse_dates=['Trade_Date']`, (2) in your df3, there are many dates with `Bins = NaN`, (3) it's `bin_value = pd.cut(g['ExecPrice'], bins, labels=False)` not `g['Price'], and (4) you should group by `Trade_Date` not `ExerPrice` in `df3['GroupPrice'] = df3.groupby('ExecPrice', group_keys=False).apply(bin_price)`

Comment: @StumblingThroughDataScience: if things are fine, please accept the solution and close the topic. Thank you